# Container xxl is not working on bootstrap 5 in angular

Tags: html, css, node.js, angularjs, media-queries

Here, I'm trying to make full responsive webpage on angular. So, I am using bootstrap version 5.0.2 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/. I used the container for all kind of devices. But it only works xl not working in xxl. I mentioned the code what i used in my component.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-xxl container-xl container-lg container-md-12 container-sm-12 gallery_update_head">
     <div class="row gallery_update_body">
          <img class="gallery_image col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12" src="\assets\img\gallery.jpg" alt="Gallery">
          <p class="gallery_update_content col-lg-6 col-md-10 col-sm-12"><span class="font-weight-bold gallery_content1">To be updated..</span><br>
              We are currently working on something awesome. Stay tuned !
          </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `class="container"` ? Or `class="container-fluid"` if you want it to be fluid?

Comment: No, I want to use only container, not container fluid and also i tried to use container, there is no changes, it gives same.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/ xxl container is the same everywhere, except for container-fluid.

Comment: I expect, xxl want to work on my page but it works upto xl

Comment: When i use only container, it also work upto xl not xxl

Comment: I edited your code and created a snipped from it, added the bootstrap CSS. If you inspect your code, the container is set for xxl. So it's unclear what's not working for you.

Comment: thank you for your valuable efforts, it's working now